# Modifying Intent used for starting IntentService results in a null GeofencingEvent from Geofence API

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using an IntentService to receive intents from the Geofence API, and a ResultReceiver to receive data from the IntentService which calls back to my MainActivity.

In the MainActivity, I have the following code:

```
private void startGeofenceService() {
    try {
        log("Initiating GeofenceService...");

        geofenceService = new GeofenceService("GeofenceService");
        log("Creating new geofence intent");
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient, getGeofencingRequest(), getServicePendingIntent()
               ).setResultCallback(this);


    }catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

which makes a call to the following:

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
        .addGeofence(createGeofence())
        .build();
    GeofencingRequest geofenceReq = builder.build();
    log("Built gefencing request: " + geofenceReq.getGeofences());
    log("Geofence initial trigger: " + geofenceReq.getInitialTrigger());
    return geofenceReq;
}
```

to build the GeofencingRequest. The PendingIntent is received from the following method:

```
private PendingIntent getServicePendingIntent() {
    GeofenceService geofenceService = new GeofenceService();
    ServiceResultReceiver serviceResultReceiver = new ServiceResultReceiver(new Handler());
    serviceResultReceiver.setReceiver(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceService.class);
    intent.putExtra(Config.RECEIVER, serviceResultReceiver);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return pendingIntent;
}
```

My IntentService subclass' `onHandleIntent()` method:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        log("GeofencingEvent: " + geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences());
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Config.RECEIVER);
        log("ServiceResultReciever retrieved from intent: " + receiver);

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.e("GeofenceService", "Error code: " + geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        log("geofenceTransition = " + geofenceTransition);
        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {
            log("Geofence triggered...");
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putBoolean(Config.COMMUTE_FINISHED, true);
            receiver.send(0, data);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("GeofenceService", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My issue seems to be in `getServicePendingIntent()`, when I remove the lines that put the ServiceResultReceiver in the Intent bundle, the IntentService always receives a null GeofencingRequest, but when I remove those lines and just use the Intent as is I get a GeofencingRequest with transition type 1. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Output example:

**With ServiceResultReceiver instance inside the intent:**

```
I/MainActivity: Initiating GeofenceService...
I/MainActivity: Creating new geofence intent
I/MainActivity: Built gefencing request: [Geofence[CIRCLE id: transitions:5 100m, resp=30s, dwell=5000ms, @-1]]
I/MainActivity: Geofence initial trigger: 1
I/GeofenceService: service created
I/GeofenceService: GeofencingEvent: null
I/GeofenceService: ServiceResultReciever retrieved from intent: android.os.ResultReceiver@6e557de
I/GeofenceService: geofenceTransition = -1
```

**Using the intent without the ResultReceiver:**

```
I/MainActivity: Initiating GeofenceService...
I/MainActivity: Creating new geofence intent
I/MainActivity: Built gefencing request: [Geofence[CIRCLE id: transitions:5  100m, resp=30s, dwell=5000ms, @-1]]
I/MainActivity: Geofence initial trigger: 1
I/GeofenceService: service created
I/GeofenceService: GeofencingEvent: [Geofence[CIRCLE id: transitions:5 6 100m, resp=30s, dwell=5000ms, @-1]]
I/GeofenceService: ServiceResultReciever retrieved from intent: null
I/GeofenceService: geofenceTransition = 1
I/GeofenceService: Geofence triggered...
```

Comment: SOLVED: just use a broadcast receiver.